# VNC connection through SSH

Tags: ssh, vnc

I have a problem, I need to establish a VNC connection with ssh, so I can have remote desktop (graphical) access to my server. I tried doing it with Remmina and it was asking me for some ssh key, but I only have the hostname and password of my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have a user. You can log in, use `ssh-keygen` (if the keys aren't already in `$HOME/.ssh`) and then you have the keys you need.